# JavaScript Promise Array Map vs For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-promise, fetch-api

Can someone help me understand why

```
for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(fetch(someUrls[i]))
}

Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(responses => responses.map(response => response.text()))
    .then(result => console.log(result))
```

and

```
Promise.all([p1,p2,p3])
    .then(results => {
        for (let result of results) {
            return result.text()
        }
    })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
```

give different results?

The latter seems to work for me but I don't understand why the former doesn't produce the same result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `return` is not magic when you use it near promises; `for (let result of results) { return result.text() }` is going to return from the function on the first value in `results`.

Comment: You can only return once. This has nothing to do with promises.

Comment: You are correct my fault, simple mistake. I've asked another question more at the point here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375974/then-executes-on-pending-rather-than-resolved-promise.