# .then Executes on 'pending' Rather than Resolved Promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-promise

Why does the following code log an array of pending promises? I expect all promises in the array to be resolved and then execute the functions inside the .then methods.

```
for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(fetch(someUrls[i]))
}

Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(responses => responses.map(response => response.text()))
    .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because [`response.text()` method returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text). `fetch` is a 2-promise thing. One is for the actual request, and the other for conversion.

What you could do is wrap the `array.map` operation in another `Promise.all`.

```
Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.text())))
    .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put chained then inside a `Promise.all` too as the `response.text()` also returns another promise.

```
for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(fetch(someUrls[i]))
}

Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.text()))) //Needs to wait for all text() promise methods to resolve
    .then(result => console.log(result))
```

or you can chain promises in your for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(fetch(someUrls[i]).then(res => res.text()));
}

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(result => console.log(result))
```